# Form not submitting , Its submit in nonwww.domain when it come with www it only reload the page

Tags: php, forms

I have a form on my website it works fine with nonwww.domain. if I try with www.domain in the same site

It won't go, Its keep on rotating after captcha, refresh page with new captcha and filled form is there.

Help me solve this error

I had this form earlier its work fine in other domain
This domain is under yahoo hosting
And 
I have not any reply from them

**Please find the code**

**Is this server error**

```
      <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="contact.css" />
      <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/fg_captcha_validator.js'></script>


<!-- Form Code Start -->
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset='UTF-8'>

<fieldset >
<legend>Contact us</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
    <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('message') ?></textarea>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='photo' >Upload your photo:</label><br/>
    <input type="file" name='photo' id='photo' /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_photo_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <div><img alt='Captcha image' src='show-captcha.php?rand=1' id='scaptcha_img' /></div>
    <label for='scaptcha' >Enter the code above here:</label>
    <input type='text' name='scaptcha' id='scaptcha' maxlength="10" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_scaptcha_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <div class='short_explanation'>Can't read the image?
    <a href='javascript: refresh_captcha_img();'>Click here to refresh</a>.</div>
</div>


<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[

    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactus");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email address");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please provide a valid email address");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("message","maxlen=2048","The message is too long!(more than 2KB!)");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("photo","file_extn=jpg;jpeg;gif;png;bmp","Upload images only. Supported file types are: jpg,gif,png,bmp");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("scaptcha","req","Please enter the code in the image above");

    document.forms['contactus'].scaptcha.validator
      = new FG_CaptchaValidator(document.forms['contactus'].scaptcha,
                    document.images['scaptcha_img']);

    function SCaptcha_Validate()
    {
        return document.forms['contactus'].scaptcha.validator.validate();
    }

    frmvalidator.setAddnlValidationFunction("SCaptcha_Validate");

    function refresh_captcha_img()
    {
        var img = document.images['scaptcha_img'];
        img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?")) + "?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
    }

// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend you spend some time to remove the duplicate content in your question

Comment: You most likely have some sort of issue with a (session) cookie here. It is probably getting set in a way so that it is not considered valid for the www domain. So when you submit your form, it doesn’t find the value to compare the code you input to, therefor the CAPTCHA validation fails, and it starts over.

Comment: What you get for `var_dump(ini_get('session.cookie_domain'));`?